# issue with FB like, a new activity gets posted in profile

Tags: facebook, android-activity, meta-tags

When a user likes a post in my website http://thewittyshit.com it adds a new activity in their profile.
I have used "og:type = article" meta content on the pages having like button.

Can somebody enlighten me on how to stop my pages from being added to my user's activity section in their FB profile?

Let me know if some other information is also required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because they like something. By like, the new feed item is automatically added to their profile/wall

Comment: My concern is not the news feed item that is generated but instead under the info (profile) -> activities section a new page is added.

Comment: @AnkitPrasad: that's news feed